# How do I link a Google sheet in a desktop sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

A user's google sheet will update all the time, I will keep that file on the desktop of my PC and whenever that user updates the sheet, the sheet in my desktop will also be updated.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to enable offline editing of your google spreadsheet and then place a shortcut on your desktop

[image]